# Designing a UITableView/Cell - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, design-patterns, uitableview

I'm designing a UITableView using subviews to populate the reusable cell of it, and I wish some opinion about that. 
As I had tested, it works well. But, I don't know if it is a good solution.

The scenario is: I have a tableview with different kind of cells (layouts). When I was designing, it grows fast (my controller code), as I had to register a lot of cell and handle cellForRow. Then I come with that idea, to instantiate different subviews for one unique reusable cell and use a 'Presenter' to handle delegate/datasource. You think is that a problem? And is that a good approach?

Thanks in advance!

Ps.: sorry for any english error!

EDITED:

Here is the session in project followed by de codes:
[image: bundle image]

Codes at:

- OrderDetailCell

  ```
  class OrderDetailCell: UITableViewCell {

  //MARK: Outlets
  @IBOutlet weak var cellHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var viewContent: UIView!

  //Variables
  var didUpdateLayout = false


  internal func setupLayoutWith(view: UIView){
  cellHeight.constant = view.frame.height
  viewContent.frame = view.frame

  viewContent.addSubview(view)

  updateConstraints()
  layoutIfNeeded()

  didUpdateLayout = true
   }
  }
  ```
- OrderDetailSubview

  ```
  class OrderDetailSubview: UIView {

  var type: OrderDetailsSubViewType?
  var height: CGFloat = 1

  class func instanceFromNib(withType type: OrderDetailsSubViewType) -> OrderDetailSubview {
  let view = UINib(nibName: type.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! OrderDetailSubview

  switch type {
  case .OrderDetailSubviewStatus:
      view.height = 258

  case .OrderDetailSubViewItem:
      view.height = 129

  case .OrderDetailSubViewStoreInformation:
      view.height = 317

  case .OrderDetailSubViewEvaluation:
      view.height = 150
  }

  view.updateConstraints()
  view.layoutIfNeeded()

  return view
   }
  }
  ```
- OrderDetailPresenter

  ```
  enum OrderDetailsSubViewType: String {

  case OrderDetailSubviewStatus = "OrderDetailSubviewStatus",
  OrderDetailSubViewItem = "OrderDetailSubViewItem",
  OrderDetailSubViewStoreInformation = "OrderDetailSubViewStoreInformation",
  OrderDetailSubViewEvaluation = "OrderDetailSubViewEvaluation"

   static let types = [OrderDetailSubviewStatus, OrderDetailSubViewItem, OrderDetailSubViewStoreInformation, OrderDetailSubViewEvaluation]
    }

  class OrderDetailPresenter {

   //Constants
   let numberOfSections = 4

  //Variables
  //    var order: Order?

   func setup(reusableCell: UITableViewCell, forRowInSection section: Int) -> OrderDetailCell {

  let cell = reusableCell as! OrderDetailCell
  for sub in cell.viewContent.subviews {
      sub.removeFromSuperview()
     }

    let subView = OrderDetailSubview.instanceFromNib(withType: OrderDetailsSubViewType.types[section])
  cell.setupLayoutWith(view: subView)

  return cell

  }

  func numberOfRowsForSection(_ section: Int) -> Int {
  switch section {
  case 1:
      //TODO: count de offerList
      return 4
  default:
      return 1
    }
   }
  }
  ```
- OrderDetailViewController

  ```
  class OrderDetailViewController: BaseViewController {

  //MARK: Outlets
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  var presenter = OrderDetailPresenter()

  override func setupView() {
    setupTableView()

     }
   }


  extension OrderDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  internal func setupTableView() {

  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

  tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OrderDetailCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OrderDetailCell")

  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return presenter.numberOfSections
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return presenter.numberOfRowsForSection(section)
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let reusableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderDetailCell") as! OrderDetailCell

  let cell = presenter.setup(reusableCell: reusableCell, forRowInSection: indexPath.section)


  return cell

   }
  }
  ```

*Sorry for indentation here...

Thats it! What you think?

Comment: If you have followed proper iOS coding practices (like `dequeueing` a cell) and your code works bug-free then it is hard to say that your code is not good. If there is an issue with your code (like crashes, logic-errors or performance problems) then edit your question to include your code and ask a specific question. If you want someone to review your code then you could try `codereview.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Thanks @RoboticCat, I had followed as recommended. The thing is, I have multiples cell types. So, instead creating many cells, I've created only one, and now I'm instantiating a subview for each row with same cell, and updating the layout. Is working well, I just wanted some opinion. Thank to the codereview suggestion too.. never heard before. I'll try!

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to have multiple `UITableViewCell` subclasses that implement the different layouts that you want, and then select the relevant one in you table view data source.

```
class Cell1: UITableViewCell {

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
    }

    ... whatever other setup/layout you need to do in the class ...

}

class Cell2: UITableViewCell {

    let imageView = UIImageView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    ... whatever other setup/layout you need to do in the class ...

}
```

Then in your view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(Cell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1Identifier")
    tableView.register(Cell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2Identifier")
}

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 { // just alternating rows for example
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1Identifier", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
        // set data on cell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2Identifier", for: indexPath) as! Cell2
        // set data on cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

So this is just an example, but is using two different cell subclasses for alternating rows in the table view.

Comment: Thank you @George! I had made that way. But the thing is, as I have multiple cells, I don't want to register all of then and make that logic at cellForRow. So, instead creating many cells, I've created only one, and now I'm instantiating a subview for each row with same cell, and updating the layout. I can share my code if you want to..

Comment: @Gehlen Please do share your code if you can. This sounds like a bad plan since you will have to reimplement the view reuse system that UITableView provides for free. This begs the question, why use a table view at all, and not just a scrollview? Why is it simpler to have custom `UIView`'s with different layouts and switch between them, than it is to have different `UITableViewCell`'s?

Comment: I've updated the question... I appreciate your opinion! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let dynamicCellID: String = "dynamicCellID" //One Cell ID for resuse
class dynamicCell: UITableViewCell {

    var sub: UIView // you just need to specify the subview

    init(sub: UIView) {
        self.sub = sub
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: dynamicCellID)

        self.addSubview(sub)
        self.sub.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sub.frame.width, height: sub.frame.height)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

And you need to create a views array the give that view to every cell in delegate

```
let views: [UIView] = []

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

                    return views.count
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                    let v = views[indexPath.row]
                    return dynamicCell(sub: v)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

                    let v = views[indexPath.row]
                    return v.frame.height + 10 //offset is 10 point
    }
```

Comment: Yes! I'm doing something like that! But using xib files and a 'View Presenter' to handle each instance for row.. The thing is: doing that way, is a great approach? I'm mean, still reusing cell, I'm handling each instance (to remove as well).. I just wanted to minimize code lines..

Comment: If you want reuse the cell for a good performance. Your need cut down the different cell as possible. Like the solution I give you  above. Your views is always in your array as a instance. it takes so many memory if you have some many views.

Comment: The only difference is that I instantiate the view in cellForRow and (to be sure) I remove subviews from the content of my cell, maybe decrease performance a little.. but still clean code.. And the scroll still smooth.. I'll keep that approach for now, until some problem show up.. Thanks!